# In C++, is it allowed to cast a function pointer to one that gets as a parameter a pointer to a base or derived class?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, function-pointers

Will the following work as expected?:

```
struct A {};

struct B: public A {
    int x;
    };

void f( B* o ) {
    std::cout << o->x << std::endl;
    }

int main () {
    B b;
    b.x = 5;
    reinterpret_cast<void(*)(A*)>(f)( &b );
    }
```

Comment: It most probably depends on the expectations...

Comment: Is this just academic curiosity, or is there a practical problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @RSahu: It has actually turned useful for me, but I prefer to keep the example as miminal as possible.

Answer (score 6):

Its undefined behaviour to use such pointer after cast:

> Any pointer to function can be converted to a pointer to a different function type. Calling the function through a pointer to a different function type is undefined, but converting such pointer back to pointer to the original function type yields the pointer to the original function.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language

So the answer to your question is actually positive - you are allowed to cast but nothing more.

You might ask "what is the point of only casting?" - this is usefull when you want to store various functions in single collection.

Answer (score 5):

See [5.2.10/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#6) [expr.reinterpret.cast]:

> A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function pointer of a different type. The effect of calling a function through a pointer to a function type that is not the same as the type used in the definition of the function is undefined.

That said, note as an example that C++ allows you to dereference a null pointer, so maybe *allowed* is not the right term.
The following command compiles too:

```
reinterpret_cast<void(*)(A*, int)>(f)( &b, 42 );
```

It is allowed, as well as the one in the question, no matter if it works as expected or not (it mostly depends on your expectations, as noted by @luk32 in the comments).

The answer to your question would be *yes, the cast is allowed, but the invokation of the function through the new pointer leads to an undefined behavior*.

Comment: Why surprising? Undefined means, anything thing can happen, not that it won't compile. Basically anything involving `reinterpret_cast` goes into off-limits. I believe there are similar statements for types too.

Comment: Right, even _surprising_ isn't the right term indeed.

Comment: I think "allowed" is actually an okay word choice here. The subtext is "is a well-formed C++ program allowed to ... ?". Actually for the reasons you point out I think "allowed" != "happens to compile"

Comment: It is allowed, but when you mix up types there is UB. IMO `reinterpret` basically turns off type checking, and standard didn't want to deal with it. OPs case will probably work not matter what, but your's is a great example, where you can blow up things, and it's easy to check whether it makes sense or not.

Comment: @ChrisBeck I tried to point out the same concept. The last sentence should sum up it: it is allowed, of course, but do not expect it to work correctly. :-)

Comment: I see now. It is a rather strange situation that they allow the cast to be performed but the resulting pointer is not useful.

Comment: @skypjack I do see however that an UB is a little over exaggeration for the OPs case. Because the altered type is "essentially" equal to the original. But this is only because the number of arguments is the same, and all are pointers (I don't think there is any difference in pointers to different types, e.g. plain object would not work due to object slicing, not sure about references). Oh, and, the parameter meets the original type. I don't think it was worth to make an exception for such a case.

Comment: @luk32 The standard states so. I'm sorry. :-)

Comment: And I can totally understand why. Technically the code is invalid and compiler can place something random in there. @ChrisBeck 1. You can always cast it again. 2. I guess it allows programmer simply go crazy when he really wants to. Like OP. This use-case should be fairly safe in practice, as the actual invocation meets the original signature... but boy it does look like turing off all the safety just for kicks.